# Saving click on close button to cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have working popup window created with HTML, CSS and jQuery, and need to display this popup to user only one time (maybe, when he clicks on close button or somewhere outside):

```js
(function($) {
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.2/jquery.modal.min.js" integrity="sha512-ztxZscxb55lKL+xmWGZEbBHekIzy+1qYKHGZTWZYH1GUwxy0hiA18lW6ORIMj4DHRgvmP/qGcvqwEyFFV7OYVQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="newsletter">
                    <div class="modal-bg">
                        <div class="newsletter-main">
                            <div class="offer-content">
                                <div>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                    <h2>newsletter</h2>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>

                                    <form action="" method="post" name="">
                                        <div class="form-group ">
                                            <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Enter your email">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme btn-normal btn-sm">subscribe</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="imd-wrraper">
                                <img src="../assets/images/cosmetic/product/18.jpg" alt="newsletterimg" class="img-fluid bg-img">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so what is your question?

Comment: Well, if `.modal('show')` works to show the modal, maybe `.modal('hide')` works to hide the modal? Please [edit] your question with what component library you're working with, and what research you've done, and any attempts you've made to solve the problem yourself. There are many questions about cookies on Stack Overflow.